# $tr(AB) = 0$ for all $B \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ implies $A = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $V= M_n(\mathbb{R})$. I'm trying to prove that the bilinear form
$$g:V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$g(A,B) = tr(AB),$$
is non-degenerate. To prove it, I tried to show that the linear transformation $T:V \rightarrow V^*$, $T(A)(B) = g(A,B)$ is an isomorphism. But, I didn't make any progress.

Comment: @TheoBendit This is not true, $g$ is not an inner-product. Just take $A$ a non-zero nilpotent matrix of order $2$, and you will have $g(A,A)=0$ whereas $A \neq 0$.

Comment: @Theo g is inner product. It is called Frobenius (or Hilbert-Schmidt) norm.

Comment: It's almost an inner product. A transpose (or adjoint) is missing...

Comment: @Salcio No, it's not an inner product since $$g\left(\begin{pmatrix}\;\;1&\;\;1\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}\;\;1&\;\;1\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix} \right)=0$$but $\;\begin{pmatrix}\;\;1&\;\;1\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix}\neq \overline 0\;$

Comment: @Gui That "linear transformation" you define at the end of your post is not well defined: $\;g(a,b)\;$ is a scalar, thus that $\;T\;$ of yours cannot have counter domain $\;V^*\;$...

Comment: @DonAntonio, $T(A) \in V^*$. So, $T(A)(B) = g(A,B) \in \mathbb{R}$. What's wrong?

Comment: @DonAntonio the $T$ is perfectly well defined; $T(A):= g(A,\cdot)$. For each $A\in V$, $T(A)$ is that element of $V^*$ such that for all $B\in V$, $[T(A)](B):= g(A,B)$.

Comment: @DonAntonio - you are right, transpose is missing, I have not noticed that, Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want is to show $g$ is non-degenerate, that's definitely possible. Suppose $A\in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R})$ is such that $g(A,\cdot)=0$. Then, in particular, $g(A,A^t)=\text{tr}(AA^t)=0$. Now, expanding out what the trace is, you can convince yourself it is $\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^na_{ij}^2$. If a sum of squares of real numbers is $0$, then each summand is zero, and hence each $a_{ij}=0$; i.e $A=0$. This proves non-degeneracy.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$ \delta_{(i,j)}(k,\ell)=\begin{cases} 1, & \mbox{ if }  (k,\ell)=(i,j)\\ 0, & \mbox{ if }  (k,\ell)\neq (i,j)\\  \end{cases} $$
and the $n\times n$ matrix $E^{k,\ell}=\Big(\delta_{(i,j)}(k,\ell)\Big)_{n\times n}$. Fix $A=\big( a_{ij}\big)_{n\times n}$. Note that for all $E^{k,\ell}$ we have
$$
\mathrm{trace}\Big(  A\cdot E^{k,\ell} \Big)=a_{k \ell}=0. 
$$
So what? What can you conclude?

Comment: If $A$ is a matrix that $tr(A\cdot B) = 0, \forall B$, using this particular case that you proposed, it implies that $A = 0$, right?

Comment: @GuilhermeCosta Yes.